R package: author appearing in the manual
I m building a basic package with devtools (think of a package containing only an Hello World function).
My DESCRIPTION file is simply:
Title: What the Package Does (One Line, Title Case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: 
    person("Jon", "Snow", , "jon.snow@gmail.com", role = c("aut", "cre"),
           comment = c(ORCID = "YOUR-ORCID-ID"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
License: `use_mit_license()`, `use_gpl3_license()` or friends to pick a
    license
Encoding: UTF-8
Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)
RoxygenNote: 7.3.2

and I'm building it by running successively:
devtools::build(); devtools::install(); devtools::build_manual()
Everything works, but the manual never prints the `author', and I don't know how to make it work. It compiles without error... I tried this previous thread but it does not work.

Did you specifically follow this answer to the thread you linked?  Can you be more specific about what "it does not work"? How are you viewing the manual (e.g., in the RStudio help panel, as a standalone PDF ...) ?

Yes I followed exactly whzt it said, it did not change anything unfortunately. I tried several times with some tweaks nothing works so far. My package is almost done it’s the only thing missing and I can’t figure out. I m viewing the manual by opening the standalone pdf, can I change something there?

I just tried the advice I originally gave, and it didn't work.  Here's a modification.
First, this is what happened with your code:
devtools::build() builds the .tar.gz file for your package.  It adds the Author field and some others to the DESCRIPTION file.
devtools::install() is not really involved here.
devtools::build_manual() ignores the .tar.gz file, and builds the manual using the source directory.
Here's a way to fix it:
devtools::install()
devtools::build_manual(system.file(package="yourpackage"),
                       path = ".")

This says to build and install the package, then using the copy that was installed, build the manual and output it to the current directory.
This worked for me.

OK, choose.dir() ?

@BenBolker:  That would work if you chose a directory where the tarball had been unpacked, but my original code didn't unpack it.  Using the install directory seems easiest, which is what the current code does.

Ok this works for me as well! Thank you :) It's reassuring to know that your other answer did not work either and it was not my fault :)

Another answer is just that your DESCRIPTION file has a bad entry for Authors. Simply replace "Authors@R" by "Authors" and it should work fine.
Title: What the Package Does (One Line, Title Case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors: 
    person("Jon", "Snow", , "jon.snow@gmail.com", role = c("aut", "cre"),
           comment = c(ORCID = "YOUR-ORCID-ID"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
License: `use_mit_license()`, `use_gpl3_license()` or friends to pick a
    license
Encoding: UTF-8
Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)
RoxygenNote: 7.3.2


There's no "Authors" field in the Writing R Extensions manual, just "Author" and "Authors@R".

Actually it also works (even though I thought "Author" was depreciated). You just need to write it with "Author" and not AuthorS.

It's a surprise to me that you can use the Authors@R input format in the Author field, but it does work.  But if you look at packageDescription("pkg") after installing, you can see that something in the build or install code has edited the field so it is recorded as Authors@R, as WRE says it should be.

Yes I know that it shouldn't work, but I just found this in case he was single author.
